# How to fix 'file keeps the original location and after being copied doesnt copy extension'?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to create a program which copy itself while it is running to new location without keeping the orignal file location . once it is copied I got the file without extension , but how can I overcome this ?

```c
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR szFilepath[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR szFilename[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR szDestpath[MAX_PATH];

    /* Get the current executable's full path */
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFilepath, MAX_PATH);
    std::wcout << "filepath: " << szFilepath << std::endl;

    /* Extract just the name */
    GetFileTitle(szFilepath, szFilename, MAX_PATH);
    std::wcout << "filename: " << szFilename << std::endl;

    //Set the destination folder path
    _tcscpy(szDestpath, L"D:\\");

    //Set the destination file path
    _tcscat(szDestpath, szFilename);

    std::wcout << "dest path: " << szDestpath << std::endl;

    // copys the file of your '.exe'

    if (!CopyFile(szFilepath, szDestpath, FALSE)) {
        std::cout << "couldnt copy the file";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "copied";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want the extension then `basename`, don't use `GetFileTitle`

Comment: how can I do this in a code level?

Comment: @victor_angel27 see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation for [`GetFileTitle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getfiletitlew):

> `GetFileTitle` returns the string that the system would use to display the file name to the user. **The display name includes an extension only if that is the user's preference for displaying file names**. This means that the returned string may not accurately identify the file if it is used in calls to file system functions.

You should be using a more suitable function to get the actual filename, such as [`PathFindFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfindfilenamew):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WCHAR szFilepath[MAX_PATH];
    LPWSTR lpszFilename;
    WCHAR szDestpath[MAX_PATH];

    /* Get the current executable's full path */
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, szFilepath, MAX_PATH);
    std::wcout << L"filepath: " << szFilepath << std::endl;

    /* Extract just the name */
    lpszFilename = PathFindFileNameW(szFilepath);
    std::wcout << L"filename: " << lpszFilename << std::endl;

    /* Set the destination folder path and file name */
    PathCombineW(szDestpath, L"D:\\", lpszFilename);
    std::wcout << L"dest path: " << szDestpath << std::endl;

    // copys the file of your '.exe'

    if (!CopyFileW(szFilepath, szDestpath, FALSE)) {
        std::wcout << L"couldnt copy the file";
    }
    else {
        std::wcout << L"copied";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or, you could simply parse the filename yourself using normal C++ string operations, eg:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WCHAR szFilepath[MAX_PATH];
    std::wstring wFilepath;
    std::wstring wFilename;
    std::wstring wDestpath;

    /* Get the current executable's full path */
    wFilepath = std::wstring(szFilepath, GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, szFilepath, MAX_PATH));
    std::wcout << L"filepath: " << wFilepath << std::endl;

    /* Extract just the name */
    wFilename = wFilepath.substr(wFilepath.find_last_of(L"\\/")+1);
    std::wcout << L"filename: " << wFilename << std::endl;

    /* Set the destination folder path and file name */
    wDestpath = L"D:\\" + wFilename;
    std::wcout << L"dest path: " << wDestpath << std::endl;

    // copys the file of your '.exe'

    if (!CopyFileW(wFilepath.c_str(), wDestpath.c_str(), FALSE)) {
        std::wcout << L"couldnt copy the file";
    }
    else {
        std::wcout << L"copied";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: talking about the file keeps the orignal location , should I remove or how come because I cannot remove in running state

Comment: Of course you can't remove the original file while the process is still running, the file is locked. You will have to exit the process first, and then perform the removal in another process (ie, by spawning another app before exiting, and have that app wait on the original process to fully exit before then removing its file), or after system reboot (via `MoveFileEx(MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT)`). But that is secondary to THIS issue.  If you want help with THAT issue, post it as a new question.